# Divide Column in Pandas Dataframe by Sum of Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe where I would like to divide each row within column A by the sum of column A and make that a new column within the dataframe.

```
Example:

        Col A   New Col
        2       .22
        3       .33
        4       .44
Total = 9       1.00
```

I tried to sum Col A and then tried to divide by 'Total' but because Total is not a column but a row, it did not work. I just get NaN for each row within the new column.

```
df['New Col']= (df['ColA']/df.loc['Total'])
```

I know you can also probably integrate a sum calculation within the one line of code instead of creating a totals row as well but not sure how to do that and could not find anything online.

```
df['New Col']= (df['ColA']/df.sum())
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 11):

```
df['new'] = df['ColA'] /  df['ColA'].sum()
```

should work

Answer (score 3):

You are very close. You want to perform the `sum()` on the `Col A` series

```
df['New Col'] = df['Col A']/df['Col A'].sum()
```

Results in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> df
   Col A   New Col
0      2  0.222222
1      3  0.333333
2      4  0.444444
```

Now if you do `df.sum()` you get a Series with the totals per column:

```
>>> df.sum()
Col A      9.0
New Col    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['New Col'] = df['ColA'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```